# Php/SQLite , use a parameter for the JOIN taken from a query?

Tags: php, sqlite, join, pdo

I have to do this with PHP on a simple SQLite database , with PDO

i have 3 table, **tableA** - **tableB**, **TableC**

### tableA

the column **TYPE** represents the name of the other tables

```
___________________________________
|ID_OBJ |  TYPE  | PROP_1 | PROP_2 |
-----------------------------------
| 1000  | tableB |    0   |  10    |
| 1001  | tableB |    1   |  10    |
| 1002  | tableC |    1   |  10    |
-----------------------------------
```

### tableB

```
____________________________
|   ID  |  PROPA   | PROPB  |
----------------------------
| 1000  |  ...     |  ....  |
| 1001  |  ...     |  ....  |
----------------------------
```

### tableC

```
____________________________
|   ID  | PROPAA   | PROPBB |
----------------------------
| 1002  |  ...     |  ....  |
----------------------------
```

what I wanted to know is: Can i , through a **JOIN** (for example a *LEFT JOIN*) do a query that return something like this?

```
_______________________________________________________________________
|ID_OBJ |  TYPE  | PROP_1 | PROP_2 | PROPA   | PROPB | PROPAA   | PROPBB|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1000  | tableB |    0   |  10    |   ...   |   ... |          |       |
| 1001  | tableB |    1   |  10    |   ...   |   ... |          |       |
| 1002  | tableC |    1   |  10    |         |       |  ...     |  ...  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I don't know how to do this, having to take the name of the table on which to perform a join from a table. So let me know if I can run a JOIN, and not having to do a query for each row present in the table **tableA**

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join) also returns rows for which no match was found:

```sql
SELECT tableA.ID_OBJ,
       tableA.TYPE,
       tableA.PROP_1,
       tableA.PROP_2,
       tableB.PROPA,
       tableB.PROPB,
       tableC.PROPAA,
       tableC.PROPBB
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.TYPE = 'tableB' AND tableA.ID_OBJ = tableB.ID
LEFT JOIN tableC ON tableA.TYPE = 'tableC' AND tableA.ID_OBJ = tableC.ID
```

If the are no 'wrong' rows in tableB/C, it is not necessary to check the type:

```sql
SELECT tableA.ID_OBJ,
       tableA.TYPE,
       tableA.PROP_1,
       tableA.PROP_2,
       tableB.PROPA,
       tableB.PROPB,
       tableC.PROPAA,
       tableC.PROPBB
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.ID_OBJ = tableB.ID
LEFT JOIN tableC ON tableA.ID_OBJ = tableC.ID
```